# Counter - Can't clear each Iteration

Tags: jmeter

I'm using Counter in Thread Group Level for using different users,

I want to execute Thread Group with more than 1 Loop Count and reset the counter each iteration, so that each iteration thread group will be the same,e.g. start from counter 1.

I expected to use `Reset counter on each Thread Group Iteration` but it's disabled unless I reset per user which I don't want.

> Reset counter on each Thread Group Iteration
>
> This option is only available when counter is tracked per User, if checked, counter will be reset to Start value on each Thread Group iteration. This can be useful when Counter is inside a Loop Controller.

I can check Reset Counter and un-check Track counter which leaves `Reset Counter` checked but it doesn't help.
[image]

Isn't there a simple solution for my simple requirement?

Example of execution: 3 Threads, 2 Loop Count will print:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Maximum value` field, if you put there `3` instead of that weird value you currently have the Counter will start behaving exactly as you expect it do behave.

[image: JMeter Counter Example]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)

Comment: Great, so for dynamic value I can use same value as Thread number ${__P(threadnum)}